# Why does this Sqlite date comparison work?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

When a Sqlite column is declared as a `timestamp`, I understand that this works:

```
import sqlite3, datetime
dbconn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
c = dbconn.cursor()
c.execute('create table mytable(title text, t timestamp)')

c.execute('insert into mytable (title, t) values (?, ?)', ("hello", datetime.datetime(2018,3,10,12,12,00)))
c.execute('insert into mytable (title, t) values (?, ?)', ("hello2", datetime.datetime(2018,3,1,0,0,00)))

d1 = datetime.datetime(2018,3,10)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2018,3,11)

c.execute("select * from mytable where t >= ? and t < ?", (d1, d2))

for a in c.fetchall(): 
    print a

# Result: (u'hello', datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 12, 12))
```

But why does it still work when column `t` is defined as `TEXT`? It seems, according to [this doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype), that the datetime will then be stored as a string. Then **why does such a `>=`, `<` comparison still work?** Is it coincidence or good practice?

```
import sqlite3, datetime
dbconn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
c = dbconn.cursor()
c.execute('create table mytable(title text, t text)')  # <--- here t has TEXT type

c.execute('insert into mytable (title, t) values (?, ?)', ("hello", datetime.datetime(2018,3,10,12,12,00)))
c.execute('insert into mytable (title, t) values (?, ?)', ("hello2", datetime.datetime(2018,3,1,0,0,00)))

d1 = datetime.datetime(2018,3,10)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2018,3,11)

c.execute("select * from mytable where t >= ? and t < ?", (d1, d2))

for a in c.fetchall(): 
    print a

# Result: (u'hello', u'2018-03-10 12:12:00')
```

The strange thing is: **if a datetime is just stored as a string, why does such a time interval comparison work?** Is it just luck that the strings are compared (how with `<` and `>`?) correctly here?

Comment: It might be because `>=` and `<` trigger a lexicographic string comparison in Sqlite, and the fact that the datetime string format `Y-M-d H:m:s` works perfectly with lexicographic order. Can someone confirm?

Comment: The ISO8601 date/time format is specifically designed to permit lexicographic sorting of date/time values. It works this way because it is designed to.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I think this is the answer, feel free to post it. The only thing I'm not sure is: are we sure `>=` and `<` trigger a lexicographic string comparison in Sqlite?

Comment: Yes it does, but the result depends on the collation sequence that is _operative_ for the query expression. For date/time values, this is usually not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date/time format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM::SS` is specifically designed to permit lexicographic sorting that corresponds to chronological sort order. So, comparisons between strings in this format work because that's the way it is designed to work.

According to the [SQLite docs](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#assigning_collating_sequences_from_sql), whenever 2 strings are compared, the applicable collation sequence is used to compare the 2 strings. The collation sequence used depends on the following rules:

> 7.1. Assigning Collating Sequences from SQL
>
> Every column of every table has an associated collating function. If no collating function is explicitly defined, then the collating function defaults to BINARY. The COLLATE clause of the column definition is used to define alternative collating functions for a column.
>
> The rules for determining which collating function to use for a binary comparison operator (=, <, >, <=, >=, !=, IS, and IS NOT) are as follows:
>
> 1. If either operand has an explicit collating function assignment using the postfix COLLATE operator, then the explicit collating function is used for comparison, with precedence to the collating function of the left operand.
> 2. If either operand is a column, then the collating function of that column is used with precedence to the left operand. For the purposes of the previous sentence, a column name preceded by one or more unary "+" operators is still considered a column name.
> 3. Otherwise, the BINARY collating function is used for comparison.

Note that storing date/time values as strings in any other format that does not compare the same lexicographically as chronologically results in date/time comparisons that are usually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> why does it still work when column t is defined as TEXT? It seems, according to > this doc, that the datetime will then be stored as a string. Then why does such > a >=, < comparison still work? Is it coincidence or good practice?

Regardless of whether column t is defined as TEXT or TIMESTAMP, the datetime is stored as a string.

> Is it just luck that the strings are compared (how with < and >?) correctly here?

Yes. In Python 2, strings are compared by the ASCII values of their characters, from left to right. So if you have two strings, "001" and "010", python compares the first characters: "0" and "0", finds them to be equal, and then compares the next characters: "0" and "1". Because "1" has a greater ASCII value than "0", the string "010" is greater than "001".

If you are worried about different datetime formats, you can use the sqlite's datetime functions (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to convert between them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Regardless of whether column t is defined as TEXT or TIMESTAMP, the datetime is stored as a string.` Why? Are you sure? The latter gives this after querying `SELECT *`: `(u'hello', datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 12, 12))`. The former gives: `(u'hello', u'2018-03-10 12:12:00')` so *there is* a difference between using TEXT or TIMESTAMP.

Comment: About the second part of your answer, what you describe is lexicographic order for strings, is that right? I think it should work with `"Y-M-D H:m:s"` dates because if Y1=Y2, then we can compare M1 and M2, if they are equal we can compare D1 and D2, etc.

Comment: To answer your first question, you need to understand what you are doing when you declare the column as `TIMESTAMP`. I believe that you passed `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES` to your `sqlite3.connect` command. This means that when you select the contents of `t`, python's sqlite3 library converts the contents of `t` from a string to a datetime.datetime object. So yes, _there is_ a difference between using TEXT or TIMESTAMP, but it does not affect how the data is _stored_ in the sqlite database.

Comment: These `strftime` calls are invalid, and are not needed anyway.

Comment: To answer your second question, I believe you are correct. As long as all of your dates are in the format you describe, the comparisons _should_ work. I would be wary of different formats, though.

Comment: @CL. Thanks, you are right. I have edited the answer to reflect this.